# how to send hex(0x526) into one byte?

Tags: python-3.x, hex, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno, pyserial

I'm using Arduino and Raspberry Pi temperature sensor (NTC 103 thermistor) is connected. When reading data ADC value I'm getting values like 512,513,526.. up to 1023. I want to transmit 0x528 in one byte.

If I want to transmit 0x528 first I have to divide ADC value into the higher byte and lower byte {0x05,0x28}. If I send that two-byte value via serial I will receive the that ADC value then if calculated I will get to know the Room temperature but I don't want this method:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0',baudrate=9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
while True:
    a=ser.read()
    print(a)
```

output when I received:

> > > b'('

Comment: You don't want this method why? It's the only one available. You cannot get `0x526` into one byte. The maximum is `0xFF`. You need two bytes for this value.

Answer (score -1):

Note that I am going to assume that the value 0x526 will not exist or is impossible in your system because it is much larger than 1023 (0x3ff). So I'm going to assume that the largest number you will send is 0x3ff.

If you REALLY want to send it in one byte you can sacrifice the 2 insignificant bits to do it. Simply shift it to the right by 2 bits and shift it back when you receive it:

```
// pseudocode:
reading = 0x241
scaled = reading >> 2
transmitByte(scaled)
```

On receiving you shift it back:

```
scaled = receiveByte()
reading = scaled << 2
```

You will lose 2 bits of precision. But for sensor data this is often good enough depending on the application.

Comment: You are also assuming that no other values to be transmitted have anything in the lower two bits. This is not stated in your answer: nor is it a practical assumption; and it is specifically contradicted by example in the question.

Comment: @user207421 I have made the assumption based on the original problem statement: sending 12 bit values from ADC in 8 bits

Comment: @AmarKumar Yes, you are sacrificing the `1` value of the lowest bit which would be converted to `0` when read back. Depending on application this is sometimes OK (the lower bits tend to just be noise anyway). There are other ways of doing things such as delta encoding (which can encode even 64 bit values in a byte - in fact, some high end music formats encode 40 bit values into one bit) but they come with their own limitations

Comment: @slebetman what you assume is correct sir. now it's working for that sensor thing and in a protocol (0x526) I'm also for some other thing that time this thing is difficult thankyou sir

Comment: The original problem statement mentions values between 512 and 1023 inclusive. This code cannot handle all those values.

Comment: @user207421 Well, according to the OP's own comment above yours my assumption turns out to be correct. You see, sometimes people are asking about XY problems. Sometimes you have to tell them that what they are asking does not makes sense and explain what XY problems are. But sometimes you happen to have enough experience (had do do something similar before) to read between the lines like I did and directly answer the Y problem. Hopefully when one does that I hope that one would also state one's assumptions like I did above

Comment: @AmarKumar If this solution works then I'd appreciate accepting this answer